# best way to display a nested object on a web page

Tags: website-design, tree

I have an object that is actually a dictionary (or a map if you know it by another name). Meaning - key:value, key:value.

The thing is that it is nested - so it is possible to have:
`key:value, key:{key:value, key:value}, key:value`

I want to display it on a webpage.

I thought about a tree structure, but it feels awkward to put on the label key:value as text.

Is there a better design pattern to display this?

Comment: The relationships are not clear (to me)

Comment: Could you provide a context to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would "key:value" be the text? wouldn't a tree be like this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZjHh2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

In this example, Key 2 and 3 are nested

Comment: actually a table is not a bad idea. Thanks. Do you know by any chance a web component that supports this? (javascript, html)

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. I do know that native tree widgets on Windows support it.